# Is there sense to run unit tests on ios6

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ios6.1

We recently started new project and `XCTest` is our framework for unit testing. We also support **ios6** in the way it works and looks as expected.

Unfortunately `XCTest` doesn't work for **ios6**. Do you think it is valuable to have possibility to run tests on **ios6**? Do you expect to get different output from it?

I can test **ios6** specific code with injecting mocked OS versioning tool. So running tests on **ios6** to check if-else cases specific to **ios6** is not the proper answer for this question (let me know if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're testing exactly, but as a general principle I'd have to say **yes, it's worth it**. Apple change quite a lot under the hood during iOS version changes and it's hard to know whether, for example, an internal bug fix or optimisation from iOS6 -> iOS7 might affect your test outcomes.

If your project supports iOS6, you really need to have your tests run on iOS6.

To get tests that run on iOS6, create a test target and select 'OCUnit' from the drop-down (XCTest is iOS7 only), or you can use something like GHUnit which also supports iOS6.

The mocking/injection thing sounds interesting but I don't think it's any replacement for properly running your tests on genuine iOS6 devices.

Comment: Thank you for answer. My unit tests are heavily written to check own implementations but numbers of them are also to check integration with frameworks. Looks like I should also keep tests for os integration

Comment: Yup, if what you're testing interacts with Apple frameworks, I'd say you definitely need to test on iOS6 too.